# Java program trying to find first and last index of word entered

Tags: java, string, indexing

I can not figure out why my program will display the first index of the word the user enters but I can not seem to get the second word to display the right index, also one other question if I would want to display the index of every letter in the word the user enters what would be the best way to go about doing that?

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Lab3practice
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       String simplePhrase;
       String  word;

       System.out.println("Enter 6 lines of text");
       simplePhrase = keyboard.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Enter a word from text to see it's index:");
       word = keyboard.nextLine();

       int wordFirstIndex = simplePhrase.indexOf(" ");
       System.out.println("Begginng index of word:"+wordFirstIndex);
       int wordLastIndex = simplePhrase.lastIndexOf(wordFirstIndex);
       System.out.println("End of index word:"+wordLastIndex);


   }
}
```

Comment: What is the "index"? e.g. index of "is" in  "this is a sample text": Is it 5 (Java string indexOf), 6 (1-based, sixth character), or 2 (second word)?

Comment: It is 5, why do you ask?

Comment: And wordLastIndex is the index of the start of the last occurrence of the word? Or the index of the last character of the word in its first occurrence (which is just the same as the startIndex + length)?

Comment: I want lastindex to be the white space after the word and want the same for the first index but I have tried everything I can think of, I cant seem to get it correct